# Node js redirect with headers

Tags: node.js, redirect, header

I am trying to perform a redirection in an application implemented with node express, to other application sending a header in the request. In the redirect response, the header is not sent to the destination.

I'm try something of this style:

```
res.header ("Authorization", authValue);
res.redirect ("http: // localhost: 5601 /")
```

and in the 302 redirection at the browser level, the added header is not included. Any idea?

Comment: Is possible that the browser that made the redirection not propage the http headers? or the http protocol not allows it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To send header values in redirecting api in nodejs all you need to do is use cookie parser or express-session

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser());
res.cookie("Authorization", authValue);
res.redirect("http: // localhost: 5601 /");
```

you will get your data in your browser cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Setting headers wouldn't work here because a res.redirect will execute a new http request.

If you want to get the AuthValue then use something like [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) to store the auth token and fetch it when you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand that node express is to simulate a session in the node server and be able to recover when necessary. The problem that localhost: 5691 is another application, specifically kibana, against which I want to perform a basic authentication, hence passing the authorization header.

Can the solution be that the redirection to kibana is through a reverse proxy or a component that propagates headers?